# Why forceUpdate doesn't work after click button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm doing a little project using ag-agrid and I'm trying to translate it.

My objetive is when user click in a button it change the language and to change the language the page must be refreshed

when click on button:

```
changeLanguage(lang) {
    this.setState({language: lang},
    this.forceUpdate());
  }
```

the problem is:

> forceUpdate() is not working

render and construtor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state ={
       language: 'pt'
    }

    this.changeLanguage = this.changeLanguage.bind(this);
}


render() {
  return (
<div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{ height: '700px', width: '95%' }}>

  <Row>
    <Button onClick={() => this.changeLanguage('pt')}> PT </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => this.changeLanguage('en')}> EN </Button>                
  </Row>

  <br/>

  <AgGridReact
     //props of grid
     localeText={this.state.language === 'pt' ? pt : en}

  />
</div>
);
}
```

I'm doing something wrong when I'm using forceUpdate?

[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-feather-gcb48)

Note: pt and en are data from a json file

Comment: Where exactly are you using `this.state.language`? Is it being passed to `AgGridReact`? How do you know `state.language` is not being updated? Please update the question to show exactly how you are using `state.language`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky language is on state of this component

Comment: Right, you are indicating that you are not seeing any updates unless you update the page. Your code does not show `this.state.language` being used anywhere or being passed anywhere. Trying to understand how exactly you know that `this.state.language` is not being update by `this.setState({language: lang})` and why you feel `forceUpdate()` is needed. Also in your example `this.setState({language: lang},` is incorrect syntax, it's missing an ending parenthesis `)` and that comma is extra, but that may have been copy/paste error

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky state is changing, I saw in console, unique thing is not working is forceUpdate that doens't re-render

Comment: Are you saying that `AgGridReact` is not re-rendering when `this.state.language` value is updated?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes, something like that, I want render function do a re-render

Comment: Okay, are you passing `this.state.language` as some sort of prop ` AgGridReact`? Is a change in `this.state.language` supposed to have a visible change in the instance of `AgGridReact`? Please update your code to show how you are **using** `this.state.language`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Updated

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky you can help?

Comment: I can try to help, but you’ll first need to create StackBlitz or Code Sandbox that has your code and JSON file, as close to a working example as possible.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky okay thanks, maybe tomorow I will make another question with code sand box

Comment: You can just add the link to the sandbox/example here and we can fork it to try to find a solution. The main thing is your locale json files

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I update now with link

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky how can you see, when you click with right button of mouse, this little menu update with translate, I just need to render table to translate it

Comment: Right click on what element/component? onClick is usually left click on element/component to trigger.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky in some cell of the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a re-render by adding a `key` property in combination with `this.state.language` to the `AgGridReact` component instead of using `this.forceUpdate()`. This should cause a re-render when you change the language via the button clicks:

```
<AgGridReact
  key={this.state.language}
  ... other props
/>
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-fog-4f32d) in action.

I don’t see any issues with your code, this seems like more of an issue with the grid component failing to update. You are updating state correctly.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for your time!

Comment: This is the correct working answer after I searched and tried a lot of other methods for this kind of problem ... thanks!